# How do I call a function from a function in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function called `getColor(params)` which returns a string to be used for CSS.

I'm trying to call it from another function but instead of the color being returned, I'm being returned the literal function body which is being inserted into my CSS.

**Calling Function**

```
coldef = (processedJson) => {
    this.customColumns.push(
        {
            headerName: "Test Set Name", field: "field1", width: 310,
            cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;' }
        });

    this.customColumns.push(
        {
            headerName: "Test Case Name", field: "field2", width: 310,
            cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;' }
        });

    for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
        var item = this.columns[i];
        this.customColumns.push(
            {
                headerName: this.columns[i], field: this.columns[i], width: 110,
                cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;', 'background-color': this.getColor }
            });
    }
}
```

My problem is the function is returning function body as text.

`this.getColor` accepts a parameter called `params`, but from my understanding this value is inserted by angular and contains my JSON object.

How can I get `getColor` to return just the string I need?

Comment: Simply add `(arguments)` to `this.getColor`. How do you normally call a function?

Comment: You need to call it as a function, `this.getColor(params)`

Comment: `this.getColor` is being called when this code runs, not when it's displayed

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley the problem is  `params` is not in scope inside the function..

Comment: Then you've got to find some way to put it into the function

Comment: This question is really much more code specific than "how do I call a function from a function in TypeScript" -- the answer to that is simply "the same as JavaScript: just call it." You need to provide more details on the context of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that `params` in angular is only in scope inside of a closure. I needed to just pass it down to `getColor`

```
 for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
     var item = this.columns[i];
     this.customColumns.push(
         {   headerName: this.columns[i], field: this.columns[i], width: 110,
             cellStyle: (params) => {
                return { 
                   'font-size': '12px;', 'background-color': this.getColor(params)
                }; 
             }
         }
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using this :

```
'background-color': this.getColor
```

while your function awaits for a parameter (according to you). Doesn't that seems strange to you ?

To call a function, you need to write the parenthesis like so :

```
'background-color': this.getColor()
```

In your case, you should also give it params, this means put something into the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `params` to the `getColor` function and then actually call it as others suggested. There are two ways how you can get params in the call:

- Pass it as an argument to `colddef` function:

```js
coldef = (processedJson, params) => {
  this.customColumns.push(
    {
        headerName: "Test Set Name", field: "field1", width: 310,
        cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;' }
    });

  this.customColumns.push(
    {
        headerName: "Test Case Name", field: "field2", width: 310,
        cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;' }
    });

  for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
    var item = this.columns[i];
    this.customColumns.push(
        {
            headerName: this.columns[i], field: this.columns[i], width: 110,
            cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;', 'background-color': this.getColor(params) }
        });
  }
}
```

- Add it to the param object/scope (this):

```js
this.params = params;

coldef = (processedJson) => {
  this.customColumns.push(
    {
        headerName: "Test Set Name", field: "field1", width: 310,
        cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;' }
    });

  this.customColumns.push(
    {
        headerName: "Test Case Name", field: "field2", width: 310,
        cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;' }
    });

  for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
    var item = this.columns[i];
    this.customColumns.push(
        {
            headerName: this.columns[i], field: this.columns[i], width: 110,
            cellStyle: { 'font-size': '12px;', 'background-color': this.getColor(this.params) }
        });
  }
}
```